# Finding ExactCenterX or Y of a control in C#

Tags: c#, drawing, controls, picturebox, bounds

If I am not wrong, in Android's view class there is a methos like `Bounds.ExactCenterX` that returns the exact center of a view.

I want to have the same exact center in a `PictureBox`. I couldnt find ExactCenterX or Y property in `Bounds` field of `PictureBox` could it be somewhere elese?

if not, does doing for example `Bounds.Width / 2F` return the exact center pixel of picturebox control? in case the Width is an odd number?

Answer (score 0):

Some basic geometry:
If you want to get the form-relative center pixel:
`Control.Location.X + Control.Width / 2` for the `X` value.
`Control.Location.Y + Control. Height / 2` for the `Y` value.
Because you divide `Integers` the `.5` that should be appended in case the `Width` or `Height` are odd will be discarded. You may change this behavior by casting to `double` or `float`.